# How to increase bcp batch load?

Tags: sql-server, bcp

is there a way to increase the number of rows sent to sql server/sec?

I have over 7M records (1.5 GB file) and it's taking around 30 mins to import all into the sql server table from the bcp file.

[image: bcp load]

Is there a way to increase this to like 10k or even 100000 rows sent everytime?
i ran into some issues with bcp until finally i resolved them, but everytime i had to debug these issues i had to wait half an hour which was frustrating. Also, we may need to load in over and over so it would be helpful to know a faster way for future bcp loads.

Some stats here:

```
7217765 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 1765235 Average : (4088.84 rows per sec.)
```

The bcp file is on a network drive, and the table DDL is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Historical_Fact](
    [Style Code] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Trim Code] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Country] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Org] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Prod Code] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Report Year] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Scen] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Volume] [decimal](25, 10) NULL,
    [EBIT] [decimal](25, 10) NULL,
    [NSR] [decimal](25, 10) NULL,
    [Measures] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Values] [decimal](25, 10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15):

> **-b batch_size**
>
> Specifies the number of rows per batch of imported data. Each batch is imported and logged as a separate transaction that imports the whole batch before being committed. By default, all the rows in the data file are imported as one batch. To distribute the rows among multiple batches, specify a batch_size that is smaller than the number of rows in the data file. If the transaction for any batch fails, only insertions from the current batch are rolled back. Batches already imported by committed transactions are unaffected by a later failure.

Comment: ya i did look at this but from my understanding, by default its 1 batch but all this -b switch does is split them up into mini batches. but how does that help improve performance? and what would be an ideal batch size in my case?

Comment: You _specifically_ asked about increasing the batch size.  The ideal batch size is probably more than 1000, but you should test.  For your other questions, add more details to your original question, including where the file is, and what the table DDL you are loading.

Comment: @Cataster See the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client-odbc-bulk-copy-operations/managing-bulk-copy-batch-sizes?view=sql-server-ver15) for recommendations

Comment: thank you charlie. from the docs it seems like this can be optimized even further if we specify `TABLOCK`? what would be the equivalent switch for that in a bcp commandline?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft updated my post. can i please get the downvote removed now? :)

Comment: `-h "TABLOCK"` you may also want `"CHECKCONSTRAINTS"`. The downvote is for not checking the docs first, and I think it is 100% justified

Comment: i honestly did check the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15#b but because theres not info on there it seemed to me like not the option i really needed to optimize performance. but the reference you posted was more helpful in understanding the -b switch more in depth. besides, i just specified the batch size at 1000 and then 10000 and it seems like its running at the same rate as the default rate...so not sure if anything really changed in terms of performance.

Comment: Personally I think if you want fastest perf, you need to do it in the biggest batch sizes with TABLOCK. Also see [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5068/220697) for more tips

Comment: oh yes with Tablock there's definitely a huge performance boost!

Comment: @Cataster I didn't downvote your question, but I'll upvote it for you.